# Validating a form for ONLY letter inputs

Tags: javascript

Im validating a form but im struggling to get it to only accept letters for firstname and lastname fields

hope u can help

heres my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// Place ID's of all required fields here.
required = ["firstname", "lastname", "email"];
// If using an ID other than #email or #error then replace it here
email = $("#email");
errornotice = $("#error");
// The text to show up within a field when it is incorrect
emptyerror = "Please fill out this field.";
emailerror = "Please enter a valid e-mail.";
onlyletters = "Only letters allowed.";

$("#theform").submit(function(){    
    //Validate required fields
    for (i=0;i<required.length;i++) {
        var input = $('#'+required[i]);
        if ((input.val() == "") || (input.val() == emptyerror)) {
            input.addClass("needsfilled");
            input.val(emptyerror);
            errornotice.fadeIn(750);
        } else {
            input.removeClass("needsfilled");
        }
    }


        // Only Letters.
    if (!/^([a-zA-Z])+$/.test(errornotice.val())) {
        errornotice.addClass("needsfilled");
        errornotice.val(onlyletters);
    }


    // Validate the e-mail.
    if (!/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/.test(email.val())) {
        email.addClass("needsfilled");
        email.val(emailerror);
    }

    //if any inputs on the page have the class 'needsfilled' the form will not submit
    if ($(":input").hasClass("needsfilled")) {
        return false;
    } else {
        errornotice.hide();
        return true;
    }
});

// Clears any fields in the form when the user clicks on them
$(":input").focus(function(){       
   if ($(this).hasClass("needsfilled") ) {
        $(this).val("");
        $(this).removeClass("needsfilled");
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Only letters? You must really want to make sure that Mr. O'Reilly can't sign up. Your regex is also limiting it to the letters a-z, so Piére will himself out of luck too.

Comment: That email regex will say "No!" to a lot of perfect good email addresses too.

Comment: Cue the RFC822 email regex http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Answer (score 1):

Should this line be testing against `errornotice.val()` or `firstname.val()`?

```
if (!/^([a-zA-Z])+$/.test(errornotice.val())) {

// Maybe this is what you intended.
// This requires adding some more variables earlier when you set email and errornotice
email = $("#email");
errornotice = $("#error");
// Add vars for first/lastname
firstname = $("#firstname");
lastname = $("#lastname");

if (!/^([a-zA-Z])+$/.test(firstname.val())) {
    firstname.addClass("needsfilled");
    firstname.val(onlyletters);
}
// then do the same for lastname
if (!/^([a-zA-Z])+$/.test(lastname.val())) {
    lastname.addClass("needsfilled");
    lastname.val(onlyletters);
}
```

However, your regex of letters only is going to eliminate a lot of valid names including apostrophes, diacritics, umlauts, etc.

Comment: im kinda new to this so any help would be appreciated

Comment: @user874658 You should ask yourself if you really want to limit names at all. I might be "Michael O'Reilly Jones-Smith the 1st"  I would personally not place restrictions on names.

Comment: if i dont validate the form though im worried people will be able to hack into my database via the php

Comment: @Gezzamondo You **MUST** validate it again in PHP whether or not you validated in JS first.  In PHP, use `mysql_real_escape_string()` on each of the vars to protect your database.  JS validation is useless for protection since anyone can still post anything they want to your script by simply creating their own form.

Comment: do you know where i can see a basic example of this as im not really sure about it

Comment: @Gezzamondo Many examples on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+mysql_real_escape_string  Generally you just need `$formvalue = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['formvalue']);`